# Asking for one of several conditions

Tags: prolog, boolean-logic, unification

I realize this is very basic, but I could not work this out from Prolog tutorials, so I hope someone here could help me solve my problem.

I have a term which is true if one of several conditions applies:

```
answer -->
  Var,
  a([Att1],[Var1]),
  a([Att2],[Var2]),
  a([Att3],[Var3]),
  {
    [one,   two,   three] = [Att1, Att2, Att3] -> Var1 = Var; % first condition
    [one,   three, two]   = [Att1, Att2, Att3] -> Var1 = Var; % second condition
    [two,   one,   three] = [Att1, Att2, Att3] -> Var2 = Var; % third condition
    [three, one,   two]   = [Att1, Att2, Att3] -> Var2 = Var; % fourth condition
  }
```

All Attributes and Variables come with a fixed value, and I want to offer "answer", if any of the conditions in the "{}" section are fulfilled - but for some reason, it doesn't work. The thing is, if I just check for one of the conditions, say, the first, it works as expected. But I don't want to copy/paste the rule 4 times because I didn't get a logical "or" to work properly.

Just to put it into words, in case I coded something completely different, the first condition is meant to say: check if *Att1* is equal to *one* and *Att2* is equal to *two* and *Att3* is equal to *three*. If that is the case, also confirm that *Var1* is equal to the value in *Var*. If not, check if any of the other conditions can be resolved.

edit: Turns out I just had a ';' too much in the code.

Comment: this doesn't work ? `[one,   two,   three, Var1] = [Att1, Att2, Att3, Var] -> true ; ... `

Comment: right, I can write it like that. Do I need to put the -> true there, or can I just link the conditions with ; ?
@CapelliC edit: I tested it with that line instead, it's still the case that if I only use one condition it words fine, but if I use all for none works.

Comment: it depends... from your description, seems that `;` should do. Do you want it to backtrack when your grammar has other alternative answers ?

Comment: @CapelliC I am not sure if backtracking is the right word. If the first conditions fails at some point, I want it to try out the next. I could just make 4 times the same rule with just one of the conditions each.

Comment: @CapelliC it works now, thank you for your help. I just noticed that the 4th condition also ends in a ';' .. dumb error